# Link Horizontal Area Cells to Vertical Data Area

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I want to link a set of horizontal cells to a data area that is vertical.

The red is the empty cells, the green is the data set.
[image: excel horizontal to vertical link]

So far I've used this formula to link it

```
='Page%Name'!CellReference
```

But the thing is when I drag the formula down to other cells, the data range is also selected downwards and not vertical.

Hope my Question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a sheet named `Page%Name` and want to return the values in column A of that sheet in another sheet then enter

```
=INDIRECT("'Page%Name'!A"&COLUMN())
```

in A1 of the other sheet and drag to the right.

Answer (score 0):

On the red worksheet, you could enter the following formula in to cell A1...

```
=OFFSET('Green Worksheet'!$A$1,COLUMN()-1,0)
```

...and copy the formula across.  This formula returns the value of the cell in the green worksheet that's offset from cell A1 by `COLUMN()-1` rows, where `COLUMN()` is the number (starting from 1) of the column on the red worksheet that the formula appears in.

If the number of rows on the green worksheet is fixed (say there 10 rows), an alternative formula would be:

```
=INDEX('Green Worksheet'!$A$1:$A$10,COLUMN())
```

This formula returns the value of the cell in the row of `'Green Worksheet'!$A$1:$A$10` given by the column number in the red worksheet.